# Swift, blurred images in UITableViewCell does not run smooth

Tags: swift, uitableview, gaussianblur

what i am trying to do is show a list with blurred images from the web. This works fine with this code in my custom UITableViewCell

```
func blurImage(image:UIImage, imageView: UIImageView) {

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    
        let inputImage = CIImage(image: image)
        let originalOrientation = image.imageOrientation
        let originalScale = image.scale

          let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
          filter?.setValue(inputImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
          filter?.setValue(15.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
          let outputImage = filter?.outputImage

          var cgImage:CGImage?

          if let outputImage = outputImage{
            cgImage = self.context.createCGImage(outputImage, from: (inputImage?.extent)!)
          }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if let cgImageA = cgImage{
                    imageView.image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageA, scale: originalScale, orientation: originalOrientation)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the problem is that the blur calculation takes sometime, and allthought its on a BG thread the scrolling is not that fast and smooth as if i don't have the blur effect at all.

Is there a way to make it run smoother OR to show a placeholder image until the blurred image is ready to been draw again resulting in smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Don't use qos: .background for user-initiated tasks. Docs say: Background tasks have the lowest priority of all tasks. Assign this class to tasks or dispatch queues that you use to perform work while your app is running in the background.